# jQuery Select2 android hide keyboard

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

We created responsive website where we are using select2. On desktop it is working very good, but on android once keyboard appears we cannot hide it.

How can we do that.

Comment: Want to know why down voted. This is really rude.

Comment: You should post some code with example what you mean exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you very much for rude replies and down votes.

But I came out with workaround. First I detect device is touch or normal by below code

```
 var isTouchDevice = 'ontouchstart' in document.documentElement;
```

Then I declare normal variable and assign it with zero and in next line if the device is touch device than I will assign -1. By this I can hide and unhide search box in select2. which in turn don't show keyboard on touch devices.

```
var m = 0;
m = isTouchDevice === true ? -1 : 0;
 $("#selacity1").select2({
  minimumResultsForSearch: m,
  width: 210
});
```

It will help to somebody.

Once again thank you for down votes.

Comment: i have tried your solution but it's not worked on android browser. this option prevents the filter textbox, but the first tap opened and automatically closed the dropdown, then second tap opens permanently. for your information

Comment: Not working, it just hide the search box in select2 but keyboard does not hide.